# How can the sum of values be approximated for infinite intervals in java

Tags: java, math, approximation, calc

I am trying to write a piece of code in java that needs to calculate the sum of values in following manner for the range [-∞, +∞]

```
K= +∞

∑ [ f( (2K+1)*x ) - f( (2K-1)*x ) ]

K= -∞
```

There are two confusions that I am facing with the calculation to produce a computationally feasible and efficient solution:

1. what value must be assumed for ∞ to approximate the calculation as above?
2. what minimum value must be used to increment K within loop, assuming that K holds fractional values too.

Comment: You know that this is a telescoping sum and actually the difference of the (separate) limits of `f(2m+1)` and `f(-2n-1)`?

Comment: Can you tell us what `f` is?

Comment: @RC f () is Cumulative Distribution Function

Comment: Are you sure K can have fractional values? The index of a sum is supposed to be an integer, otherwise this would be an integral.

Comment: @RealSkeptic absolutely sir

Comment: @LutzL Sir but as we know that value of infinity can't be defined, so what value can be used to approximate ∞ in a programming language like java.

Comment: Please reformulate your question to give more details about the broader situation. What problem led you to evaluate that sum. Where do you get the idea that the summation index `K` might assume rational values. -- If `f` is really a CDF then the answer is `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in order to get an approximation you need the value to decrease dramatically.  For example, `-1/x`.  If `x` increases much the answer will be near zero.

1. What value must be assumed for `∞` to approximate the calculation as above?

```java
for ( float k = 0 ; ; k++ ) 
{
    sum += (((2 * ( k) + 1) * x) - ((2 * ( k) - 1) * x));   //adding from 1 to infinity
    sum += (((2 * (-k) + 1) * x) - ((2 * (-k) - 1) * x));    //adding from -1 to infinity
}
```

but this will result in an infinite loop.  You can replace `x` with `1/x` and increase `x` each time in the loop.  The code becomes

```java
if ( (sum - lastsum) < 0.001 )
{
    break;
}
    lastsum = sum;
}
```

2. What minimum value must be used to increment `K` within [the] loop, assuming that `K` holds fractional values too?

This is according to the type of `K`.  If it is `double`, it could have up to 15 decimal places.

In addition, in the summation, you should move by one, not a fraction.  See
https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/d/f/2/df26e1cf51b67fbedd01ce9c68cbbef5.png
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation